# Is there a list of Japanese radicals, with ALL of their possible alternative writing of them?

Tags: discussion, kanji

it's easy to find lists of the radicals, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kanji_radicals_by_frequency#Table_of_kanji_radicals

However, many radicals have a lot more than one way of being written. As far as I understand, for example, there is a radical 戸. That does appear in the list I posted.

What does not appear in that list are the following variations of that radical, that as far as I understand are all considered to be the radical 戸: 戶 and 户.

Is there a list of all the radicals, such as the wikipedia one, which lists *all alternative ways that radical can appear* in kanji?

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to know about "radicals"? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65662/how-to-know-all-kanji-with-certain-radical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a complete list, but the [sci.lang.japan FAQ website](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/afaq.html) has a table of [radicals with their names](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/radical-names.html) and includes both 戶 and 戸.

BTW, I don't think 户 is used in Japanese kanji. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%B6):

> **Alternative forms**
>
> - 戶 (top stroke connects to left stroke) - used in Taiwan and South    Korea.
> - 戸 (top stroke is a horizontal line that does not connect to    other strokes, as found in the historical Kangxi dictionary) - used
>     in Japan.
> - 户 (top stroke is a slanting dot) - used in mainland China    and Hong Kong.
>
>   Note also the different stroke order: 户 and 戸 have the leftmost 丿 as
>     the final (fourth) stroke, while 戶 (this character) has  丿 as the
>     second stroke.

Comment: Japanese people commonly use the dotted form in handwriting.　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13198936558

Comment: I *think* this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. It lists it as 戶 as "63.1" and  戸 as "63.2", and it gives them the same meaning, so I think it fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

It may not have all the variant forms which you are looking for, but the most comprehensive list on the internet that I am aware of is this one:

http://www.natubunko.net/kotoba03.html

This site is all in Japanese. This site includes lots of variant names of radicals like よつてん for the れっか (below-fire) radical. Another thing which makes it more comprehensive than most is that it also includes the kanji versions of the radical names, like 三水 for "sanzui", where almost all the other sites only have kana names.

(In case it isn't clear, you need to click on the radicals on the page above to go to the more comprehensive information pages. There is one sub-page for each stroke count of radicals, I think.)